# Help me to solve the issues in j2me-polish

Tags: java, java-me, mobile-application, j2mepolish

Im  a j2me programmer.I does not know j2me-polish.
  I develop an application in j2me which is using the FileConnection API (jsr75.jar) and the Bluetooth (jsr082.jar).The j2me project works correctly.

But i converted that into j2me polish then it cause some error.
  For both im using eclipse ide.

I created a new j2me-polish  project.Then i copy the files in the src folder of the j2me projecct into the "source/src" folder of j2me-polish project.
  Then i select the my j2me-polish project,right click it,then i select "properties" then i select "java build path",the i add the jars such as "btapi.jar" (\J2ME-Polish\import\btapi.jar) and "pdapi.jar" (\J2ME-Polish\import\pdapi.jar).

Then i run the j2me-polish application .
  The the following errors is arised,

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build.xml

test:

init:

j2mepolish:   [j2mepolish] info: the license attribute is no longer supported. Please place your license.key file either to ${project.home} or to ${polish.home}.   [j2mepolish] J2ME Polish
2.0-RC4 (GPL License)   [j2mepolish] Loading device database...   [j2mepolish] Using locale [en_US]...   [j2mepolish] assembling resources for device [Generic/DefaultColorPhone].   [j2mepolish] preprocessing for device [Generic/DefaultColorPhone].   [j2mepolish] Warning: CSS-Style [focused] not found, now using the default style instead. If you use Forms or Lists, you should define the style [focused].   [j2mepolish] Warning: CSS style [title] not found, you should define it for designing the titles of screens.   [j2mepolish] processing locale code...    [j2mepolish] Warning: unable to resolve path to API "mmapi". When this leads to problems, please register this API in [apis.xml].   [j2mepolish] Warning: unable to resolve path to API "wmapi". When this leads to problems, please register this API in [apis.xml].   [j2mepolish] Warning: unable to resolve path to API "pdaapi". When this leads to problems, please register this API in [apis.xml].   [j2mepolish] Warning: unable to resolve path to API "jtwi". When this leads to problems, please register this API in [apis.xml].   [j2mepolish] compiling for device [Generic/DefaultColorPhone]. [j2mepolish-javac-Generic/DefaultColorPhone] Compiling 227 source files to C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\classes
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:15: package javax.bluetooth does not exist
       [javac] import javax.bluetooth.BluetoothConnectionException;
       [javac]                       ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:16: package javax.bluetooth does not exist
       [javac] import javax.bluetooth.DeviceClass;
       [javac]                       ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:17: package javax.bluetooth does not exist
       [javac] import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryAgent;
       [javac]                       ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:18: package javax.bluetooth does not exist
       [javac] import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryListener;
       [javac]                       ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:19: package javax.bluetooth does not exist
       [javac] import javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice;
       [javac]                       ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:20: package javax.bluetooth does not exist
       [javac] import javax.bluetooth.RemoteDevice;
       [javac]                       ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:21: package javax.bluetooth does not exist
       [javac] import javax.bluetooth.ServiceRecord;
       [javac]                       ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:22: package javax.bluetooth does not exist
       [javac] import javax.bluetooth.UUID;
       [javac]                       ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:28: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol: class DiscoveryListener
       [javac] public class BluetoothHandler implements DiscoveryListener {
       [javac]                                          ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:37: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : class LocalDevice
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.BluetoothHandler
       [javac]     private LocalDevice local = null;
       [javac]             ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:38: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : class DiscoveryAgent
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.BluetoothHandler
       [javac]     private static DiscoveryAgent agent = null;
       [javac]                    ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:55: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : class RemoteDevice
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.BluetoothHandler
       [javac]     private RemoteDevice devic = null;
       [javac]             ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:170: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : class RemoteDevice
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.BluetoothHandler
       [javac]     public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice device, DeviceClass dclass) {
       [javac]                                  ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:170: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : class DeviceClass
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.BluetoothHandler
       [javac]     public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice device, DeviceClass dclass) {
       [javac]                                                       ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:257: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : class ServiceRecord
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.BluetoothHandler
       [javac]     public void servicesDiscovered(int transID, ServiceRecord[] serviceRecord) {
       [javac]                                                 ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:443: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : class RemoteDevice
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.BluetoothHandler
       [javac]     private void doServiceSearch(RemoteDevice device) {
       [javac]                                  ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\Log.java:11: package javax.microedition.io.file does not exist
       [javac] import javax.microedition.io.file.FileConnection;
       [javac]                                  ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\PrinterCommands.java:12: package javax.microedition.io.file does not exist
       [javac] import javax.microedition.io.file.FileConnection;
       [javac]                                  ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\de\enough\polish\log\file\FileLogHandler.java:34: package javax.microedition.io.file does not exist
       [javac] import javax.microedition.io.file.FileConnection;
       [javac]                                  ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\de\enough\polish\log\file\FileLogHandler.java:35: package javax.microedition.io.file does not exist
       [javac] import javax.microedition.io.file.FileSystemRegistry;
       [javac]                                  ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:199: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : variable DiscoveryListener
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.BluetoothHandler
       [javac]             case DiscoveryListener.INQUIRY_COMPLETED:
       [javac]                  ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:230: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : variable DiscoveryListener
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.BluetoothHandler
       [javac]             case DiscoveryListener.INQUIRY_ERROR:
       [javac]                  ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:241: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : variable DiscoveryListener
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.BluetoothHandler
       [javac]             case DiscoveryListener.INQUIRY_TERMINATED:
       [javac]                  ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:261: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : variable ServiceRecord
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.BluetoothHandler
       [javac]                         ServiceRecord.NOAUTHENTICATE_NOENCRYPT, false);
       [javac]                         ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:285: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : variable SERVICE_SEARCH_ERROR
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.BluetoothHandler
       [javac]         if (respCode == SERVICE_SEARCH_ERROR) {
       [javac]                         ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:296: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : variable SERVICE_SEARCH_COMPLETED
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.BluetoothHandler
       [javac]         if (respCode == SERVICE_SEARCH_COMPLETED) {
       [javac]                         ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:330: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : variable SERVICE_SEARCH_TERMINATED
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.BluetoothHandler
       [javac]         if (respCode == SERVICE_SEARCH_TERMINATED) {
       [javac]                         ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:375: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : variable SERVICE_SEARCH_NO_RECORDS
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.BluetoothHandler
       [javac]         if (respCode == SERVICE_SEARCH_NO_RECORDS) {
       [javac]                         ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:385: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : variable SERVICE_SEARCH_DEVICE_NOT_REACHABLE
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.BluetoothHandler
       [javac]         if (respCode == SERVICE_SEARCH_DEVICE_NOT_REACHABLE) {
       [javac]                         ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:411: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : variable LocalDevice
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.BluetoothHandler
       [javac]             local = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
       [javac]                     ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:428: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : variable DiscoveryAgent
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.BluetoothHandler
       [javac]             if (!agent.startInquiry(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC, this)) {
       [javac]                                     ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:445: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : class UUID
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.BluetoothHandler
       [javac]             agent.searchServices(null, new UUID[]{new UUID(0x1101)}, device,
       [javac]                                            ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:445: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : class UUID
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.BluetoothHandler
       [javac]             agent.searchServices(null, new UUID[]{new UUID(0x1101)}, device,
       [javac]                                                       ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:480: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : class BluetoothConnectionException
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.BluetoothHandler
       [javac]             } catch (BluetoothConnectionException bce) {
       [javac]                      ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:482: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : variable BluetoothConnectionException
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.BluetoothHandler
       [javac]                 if (bce.getStatus() == BluetoothConnectionException.TIMEOUT) {
       [javac]                                        ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:531: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : class BluetoothConnectionException
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.BluetoothHandler
       [javac]                 } catch (BluetoothConnectionException bce) {
       [javac]                          ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\BluetoothHandler.java:538: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : variable BluetoothConnectionException
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.BluetoothHandler
       [javac]                     if (bce.getStatus() != BluetoothConnectionException.TIMEOUT) {
       [javac]                                            ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\Log.java:31: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : class FileConnection
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.Log
       [javac]             FileConnection file = (FileConnection) Connector.open(fileName);
       [javac]             ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\Log.java:31: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : class FileConnection
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.Log
       [javac]             FileConnection file = (FileConnection) Connector.open(fileName);
       [javac]                                    ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\PrinterCommands.java:112: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : class FileConnection
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.PrinterCommands
       [javac]         FileConnection file = null;
       [javac]         ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\com\evolute\mbs\PrinterCommands.java:116: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : class FileConnection
       [javac] location: class com.evolute.mbs.PrinterCommands
       [javac]             file = (FileConnection) Connector.open(LOGO_PATH + logoName
       [javac]                     ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\de\enough\polish\log\file\FileLogHandler.java:125: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : class FileConnection
       [javac] location: class de.enough.polish.log.file.FileLogHandler
       [javac]      FileConnection connection = null;
       [javac]      ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\de\enough\polish\log\file\FileLogHandler.java:130: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : variable FileSystemRegistry
       [javac] location: class de.enough.polish.log.file.FileLogHandler
       [javac]          Enumeration enumeration = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();
       [javac]                                    ^
       [javac] C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test\Generic\DefaultColorPhone\en_US\source\de\enough\polish\log\file\FileLogHandler.java:153: cannot find symbol
       [javac] symbol  : class FileConnection
       [javac] location: class de.enough.polish.log.file.FileLogHandler
       [javac]              connection = (FileConnection) Connector.open( url, Connector.READ_WRITE );
       [javac]                            ^
       [javac] 44 errors
       [javac] An internal class of J2ME Polish could not be compiled. Please try a clean rebuild by either calling "ant clean j2mepolish" or by removing the working directory "C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build\test".
       [javac] When an API-class was not found, you might need to define where to find the device-APIs. Following classpath has been used: [C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\J2ME-Polish\import\midp-2.0.jar;C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\J2ME-Polish\import\cldc-1.1.jar;]. BUILD FAILED C:\Users\sivakumar.j1\j2me_polish_workspace\transactionApp1\build.xml:114: Unable to compile source code for device [Generic/DefaultColorPhone]: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details. Total time: Total Time: 7 seconds
```

I  does not know how to solve the issues.Please help me to solve the issues.

Thanks  & Regards,

Comment: The issue is with your build.xml file, please post your build.xml file and read http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/documentation/building/

Answer (score 0):

I get the similar error.But i copy the "Generic default color phone" setting in device.xml and append it next to it.Change the name and add the "btapi" in the capability,Hence new custom device is added.Then i create a project and set the device as the new device.Then it will works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Java ME SDK 3.0. It's a matter of which packages your selected device in the project supports.

This solution worked:

1. Open the properties of the project.
2. Go to the "Platform" section
3. Change the device to any device, for example "DefaultCldcPhone1". Please, NOT "DefauldCldcJtw...".

Now, in the list of optional package in the same window, you see more packages and also the "File Connection and PIM optional packages 1.0". Good luck.